# Static property not accessible in decorator class

Tags: reactjs, decorator, react-typescript, typescript-decorator

I have a class that has a class decorator added to it. Because of the decorator, the static methods and properties are not accessible. On trying to access the property getting `undefined` on the property.

```
@BackInTimeWrapper()
class BarChart2 extends React.Component {
  static staticValues = {
    events: ["seriesClick"],
  };

  render() {
    return (<div>Sample</div>)
  }
}
```

```
class NewChart extends React.Component<any> {
  render() {
    console.log("Static Props", BarChart2.staticValues); // getting undefined here
    return (<BarChart2 {...this.props as any} />)
  }
}
```

The same is happening for static methods as well. Should static variables not be used in a class that uses decorator ?

Comment: Same thing happening with me. What you can do to get around the issue is to declare static properties imperatively like this:
`BarChart2.staticProp = true;`
Even then you might get the following TypeScript error:
`Property 'staticProp' does not exist on type 'typeof BarChart2'.`